# .modal-header shows 1px white border

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I've tried every possible combination of `border-radius:`, `background:` and `background-color:` on `.modal-content` and `.modal-header`, but no matter what I do, I still get the 1px white border at the top of the header:

[image: Bad Border Example]

What can I do to eliminate the border at the top of my modal dialog's header?

Comment: Show us some code, buddy!  Or even a link to the site would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `box-shadow` was being applied to `.modal-header` in a non-bootstrap style sheet.  What made this really insidious was that it was a 1px WHITE shadow - clearly rendering like a border - no idea why I or anyone else would do this, but you live, you learn.

```
.modal-header {
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    /** OFFENDER! **/
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 9px 15px 10px;
    background: #fcfcfc; /* Old browsers */   
}
```

Whew, this was a toughy! Thanks for the input.

Comment: You really don't need the vendor prefixes for box-shadow or border-radius anymore...

Answer (score 0):

If the container of the modal doesn't have the modal style your looking to edit, perhaps the modal has a header `<div>` that is sitting right over the top.